# Be directly in file name when saving an image

Tags: keyboard, firefox, 22.04, downloads, filename

Version: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Hey there! Whenever I download an image using the `Firefox Web Browser`, I get presented with the following screen:
[image]

When I donwload something, I usually want to change the name of the file right away, and **not** have it be something like `sample_apwdeoiuhrp9qwe8ihrp9uhiuh12uh3.jpg`.
But when I try to type, I'm not in the "adress bar". I instead have to manually move my mouse to the thing, select the file name, but not select all of it because of the file extentention, and then click save.

I want the process to be like this:

- click `save image as`
- be in the filename, everything until the extention is selected
- if you start typing, you will instantly be able to change the filename, but not change the extention

I've searched for solutions, but couldn't find much. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: This should probably be reported to FireFox team as a bug fix / enhancement.

Comment: Try the package version of firefox instead of the snap version.  The snap version is locked down several ways: only allowing downloads to go to the downloads directory for instance,.